# core dumped with C++ std::map<int, const string>

Tags: c++, string, std, stdmap

**Update: the previous code does not accurately describe my problem. Now changed:**

Below is a few lines of code of my program (C++ on Linux). My program often (but not always) crashes at the lines LINE_A and LINE_B

```
  class A{
      //...
      map<int, const string> m_int2StrMap;
      //...
      void problematic(){
        //...insert and erase of m_int2StrMap are involved
        char temp[6] = {0};
        int key = 12345;
        //...temp's elements and key might be changed
        map<int, const string>::iterator iter = this->m_int2StrMap.find(key);
        if(iter != this->m_int2StrMap.end())
        {
        /*LINE_A*/  this->m_int2StrMap.erase(iter); 
        }
        /*LINE_B*/  this->m_int2StrMap.insert(pair<int, const string>(key, string ((const char*)temp, 6)));  
        //...
      }
      //...
  }
```

I used gdb to backtrack the core dumps generated, some gave me this info:

```
  (gdb) bt
  #0  0x00ae0410 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
  #1  0x00138df0 in vfprintf () from /lib/libc.so.6
  #2  0x0013a701 in vfprintf () from /lib/libc.so.6
  #3  0x0017128b in __wcstod_internal () from /lib/libc.so.6
  #4  0x00179595 in ____wcstof_l_internal () from /lib/libc.so.6
  #5  0x001799d9 in ____wcstof_l_internal () from /lib/libc.so.6
  #6  0x05bfd581 in operator delete () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
  #7  0x05bda14d in std::string::_Rep::_M_destroy () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
  #8  0x08084bf7 in problematic() at /usr/lib/gcc/i386-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/basic_string.h:233
```

and some showed:

```
  (gdb) bt
  #0  0x00b81410 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
  #1  0x009ccdf0 in vfprintf () from /lib/libc.so.6
  #2  0x009ce701 in vfprintf () from /lib/libc.so.6
  #3  0x00a0528b in __wcstod_internal () from /lib/libc.so.6
  #4  0x00a0e250 in ____wcstof_l_internal () from /lib/libc.so.6
  #5  0x00a0fd87 in wcsxfrm_l () from /lib/libc.so.6
  #6  0x05bfeab7 in operator new () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
  #7  0x05bda0fb in std::string::_Rep::_S_create () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
  #8  0x05bdaef5 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
  #9  0x05bdaff1 in std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
  #10 0x080843e4 in probblematic() at bad.cpp:LINE_B
```

Is there anything unsafe in my code shown above? Thanks

Comment: Do not store char array inside a map.

Comment: But I am using string here, is this bad too? What is a better way to maintain a structure of int to char array mapping?

Comment: I don't get it, how are you expecting to insert in this map, if value is const? map<int, const string> int2StrMap

Comment: Your `temp` does not seems properly initialized. You may make it larger, and use `snprintf` to fill it, then make a `std::string` out of it. You should compile with `g++ -Wall -g`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: temp may hold any value btw 0 and 255, and I don't want to treat it as a null-terminated C-string. But I know its length will always be 6.

Comment: Then you should declare `struct sixchar_st { char s[6]; };` and use `map<int, struct sixchar_st> int2StrMap`

Comment: @user2975098 But it looks like the standard library is treating it as a null-terminated string. It's 6 nulls. I'm not sure what the behavior of that constructor is supposed to be, when the size given is larger than the string the pointer points to. I think this is a case where: what are you trying to do with temp? Why are you storing it in a string??

Comment: There is nothing technically wrong with your code, other than the method is private.  What is the context you are calling this? I'd venture a guess you are calling this from multiple threads which would be unsafe and could cause the crash.